# Appending Item to list in a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Drinks:
  def __init__(self):
    self.drink = ['Coke']
    self.count = 0
    self.alcohol_level = [1]
def main():
    Drinks().alcohol_level.append(89)
```

I want to append to the level list, not quite sure how to go about it.

What I've tried is:

```
    Drinks().alcohol_level.append(89)
```

But that's obviously not correct. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: '**D**ef main():'??

Comment: Are you trying to append a string to the list `level` for an object, or are you trying to append the string to the class list `level` itself?

Comment: @eyllanesc sorry, was supposed to be lowercase. Fixed it.

Comment: @Miket25 Im trying to append into the list level. So then if I printed the list it'd be:

[1, "whatever"]

Comment: Right I understand you want to append it in the list so that when you print you get the new element, but my question is does it update the class such that new instances get this update or is it for one object?

Comment: As of now, the line of code `Ditto().level.append("whatever")` create an instance of `Ditto` and `"whatever"` is appended to that instance's list, but the instance becomes discarded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, your class definition is fine. Good job!

Bad news, I think, you're misunderstanding how instances of classes work.

`Drinks()` is a constructor that returns a type `Drink`.

If you wanted to create an instance of type `Drink` you would use do `d = Drinks()`. `d.alcohol_level` is now `[1]`.

To answer you question, suppose you call `d.alcohol_level.append(2)`.

`d.alcohol_level`  is now `[1, 2]`

If you created `b = Drinks()`, `b.alcohol_level` is `[1]` since `alcohol_level` is an instance variable and each instantiation, or call to your `Drink` constructor, creates a `Drink` object with its own properties defined in your class.

```
def main():
  d = Drinks()
  d.alcohol_level.append(2)
  # print(d.level) -> [1, 2]

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Your original idea was close but you lose reference to that modified Ditto instance after the line `Ditto().level.append(2)`.

You did the Python equivalent of doing your homework then burning it immediately after.